# Cómo puedo hacer para que esta función PHP no repita el mensaje?

Tags: php

estoy intentando imprimir una variable que tiene como valor una serie de nombres y apellidos, para luego mostrar los nombres completos junto con un mensaje.

El contenido esperado del mensaje sería algo como: 
"Hoy están de cumpleaños: nombre1+apellido1, nombre2+apellido2, nombre3+apellido3, ..nombreN+apellidoN..". He aquí la estructura del códuigo:

Consulta SQL que selecciona el nombre y apellido de aquellas personas que están cumpliendo años en el día actual:

```
<?php $cumpleDia2 = pg_query($conexion,"SELECT p_nombre, p_apellido FROM atos_personal WHERE extract(month from fec_nac) = extract(month from NOW()) AND extract(day from fec_nac) = extract(day from NOW())");?>
```

Luego guardo los resultados de dicha consulta en un array, ejecuto la funcion nombres() y le paso el array como parámetro:

```
while ($fila = pg_fetch_array($cumpleDia2)) {
          nombres($fila);
        }
```

En la función nombres(), lo que trato de hacer en ella es asignar en las posiciones de los resultados del array, concatenarlos y ordenar cada resultado con una coma (,) y un espacio ($nbsp), posteriormente, envío el nombre completo a la función enviarSMS():

```
function nombres($fila){
          $nombre[] = $fila['p_nombre'];
          $apellido[] = $fila['p_apellido'];
          $nombrecompleto = $nombre[0] . ' ' . $apellido[0];      
          $na = $nombrecompleto ."<p>, &nbsp</p>";
          enviarSMS($na);
        }
```

La función enviarSMS(), recibe como parámetro los nombres completos de las personas que están cumpliendo años, los nombres los concateno con un mensaje ($sms), pero dicho mensaje no se muestra como esperaba, dado que el mismo se repite tantas veces como sea el número de personas que coinciden con la consulta.

Funcion enviarSMS():

```
function enviarSMS($trabajadores)
        {
            $user = "user";
            $pwd = "pwd";
            $port = "x";
            $num_tlf= "xxx-xxxxxxx";
            $sms = "Hoy están de cumpleaños: " . $trabajadores;

            //echo "<script language='javascript'>window.open('http://192.168.10.220/cgi/WebCGI?1500101=account=$user&password=$pwd&port=$port&destination=$num_tlf&content=$sms','_blank')</script>";
            echo $sms;
        }
```

Cómo podrán observar, no ejecuto el Js que abriría una nueva ventana y enviaría el SMS, si no que muestro el contenido de la variable $sms. Mi problema radica en que cuando lo hago, me muestra el sms de esta manera: "Hoy están de cumpleaños: JESUS RAMOS, Hoy están de cumpleaños: JORGE RODRIGUEZ,". La estructura del mensaje que deseo es: "Hoy están de cumpleaños: JESUS RAMOS, JORGE RODRIGUEZ, .. ^N"

De qué manera podría hacerlo?
Agradecería mucho la ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Tienes que enviar el string ya finalizado a tu función enviar SMS, es decir al terminar el while, y no durante este

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba la siguiente forma de hacerlo. Primero tienes que hacer la construcción del string mucho antes de mandar llamar la función de enviar SMS, dado que si lo haces por fila se te repetirá el mensaje como el problema que mencionas. Entonces primero sería modificar el `while`

```
$finalString;
while ($fila = pg_fetch_array($cumpleDia2)) {
      $finalString = $finalString . nombres($fila);
    }
enviarSMS($finalString);
```

Si te fijas, primero definí una variable que irá guardando todos los nombres que te regresará la función `nombres()` y al terminar el ciclo es cuando mandas llamar la función de enviar mensaje, ahora toca modificar la misma

```
function nombres($fila){
      $nombre[] = $fila['p_nombre'];
      $apellido[] = $fila['p_apellido'];
      $nombrecompleto = $nombre[0] . ' ' . $apellido[0];      
      $na = $nombrecompleto ."<p>, &nbsp</p>";
      return $na;
    }
```

Aquí regresaremos el string con los nombres conforme vas recorriendo las filas de tu consulta SQL, que se irá regresando al `while` para ir así armando el string.

Finalmente tu función de `enviarSMS()` quedaría igual:

```
function enviarSMS($trabajadores)
    {
        $user = "user";
        $pwd = "pwd";
        $port = "x";
        $num_tlf= "xxx-xxxxxxx";
        $sms = "Hoy están de cumpleaños: " . $trabajadores;

        //echo "<script language='javascript'>window.open('http://192.168.10.220/cgi/WebCGI?1500101=account=$user&password=$pwd&port=$port&destination=$num_tlf&content=$sms','_blank')</script>";
        echo $sms;
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Yikarus. Estuve probando los cambios que me recomendaste, efectivamente ya no se repite el mensaje, sin embargo, el $sms que ahora muestra es: "Hoy están de cumpleaños: 0", en la función nombres() verifico el valor de $na (haciéndole un "echo"), el cual muestra correctamente los nombres y apellidos de cada persona, no entiendo porqué al retornar el valor de $na al while, el valor se hace igual a cero.

Comment: Listo, es que puse mal la concatenación, estaba pensando en Javascript por lo que puse `$finalString += nombres($fila);` cuando debe ser `$finalString = $finalString . nombres($fila)`

Comment: Debí haber reconocido que era un error por la concatenación, mil gracias por tu ayuda!